# Transactional annotaion in Spring boot app with multiple data sources is not working as expected

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, transactional

I have a public method annotated with @Transactional that calls a private method that calls another private method that calls dao.save(...)

but when the save call is executed I get the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
```

If I put the annotation at the type level it works but then the transaction stay open for way to long.

There are 2 data sources and transaction managers one for postgres and one for mysql.  I am calling out the mySql txn manager at the method level @Transactional(value = "mySqlTransactionManager"), but it still isn't working.

Obviously I am missing something but I don't know what.

EDIT

Turns out this was a transative dependency issue.  The dao was coming from a shared dao artifact and extended a custom shared abstract generic dao. In the implementation of the generic dao a number of assumptions were made about the entity and transaction ***manager***, not mangers.

Comment: is your public method a mysql tx and the private postgres? or viceversa??

Comment: No, the issues was a transitive dependency that was creating its own generic dao that was not properly managing the transaction and assumed there would only ever be a single data source.